# reproducir audio

Tags: asp.net

Tengo una página aspx para reproducir audio

```
<audio controls 
    src='<%#poner_fichero()%>' >
</audio>
```

En codebehind tengo

```
Function Poner_fichero() As String
    Dim strfichero As String
    strfichero = "Canciones_publico/" & 
    Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("fichero"))
    Return strfichero
End Function
```

Pero nunca llama a la función, y me pone en la página html audio controls src=''

¿Cómo hacerlo bien?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: No tendrá algo que ver que `poner` está con `p` minúscula en el lado del aspx??'